# Numeric keyboard. Dot instead of comma

Tags: linux, locale, redhat

In layman terms my goal is to change how the "dot" button on numeric keyboard behave. Now once tapped it produces a "comma". I need it to produce a "dot".

After research I started toting with locale. Apparently my locale is set to en_US:

```
[xxx@xxx ~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've looked into what i presume is a proper config file for this particular locale:
    /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US

and looked for anything that might be related to "dot", "decimal separator" etc. Found LC_MONETARY and LC_NUMERIC, however mon_decimal_point for monetary and decimal_point for numeric were already set to  - which I'm quite sure is a "dot".

Just for giggles I also changed mon_thousands_sep and thousands_sep to  and restarted. No help here.
My machine:
RHEL 
xxxx@xxxxx ~]$ uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 15 02:06:41 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Now - this is a corporate computer with some strict security policies in place, so it would not be possible for me to just

```
yum -install some_magic_keyboard_mapping_app
```

I need to change it the old style. 
I have a virtual machine set up, so I can mess it up as much as i want prior to changing things on my work laptop.

Comment: Complain to your IT department.

Comment: Check X.Org server keyboard layout.

Answer (score 7):

CentOS 7.7

I had the same problem. My locale is set to en_US.UTF-8 but my keyboard is Swedish. The localized decimal separator in Sweden is a comma so I guess by default it is actually correct but most software is not aware of this so it is generally a problem. I found a simple solution. On the command line just do (root privileges not required):

setxkbmap -option kpdl:dot

To query the keyboard settings do:

setxkb -query

To clear all set options do:

setxkbmap -option ''

See this post for more details:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/209636/how-to-change-decimal-comma-to-decimal-period-in-numpad

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from Linux/GNU. I pressed <kbd>.</kbd>  button on the numeric keyboard, but the result was as if I had pressed the <kbd>,</kbd> button.

I was able to solve my problem by changing the keyboard configuration in the **System Settings → Region & Language → Input Sources** option. The language of my country is Portuguese but I changed the language to English and the problem is over.